# While creating a YAML Pipeline, can we use library variables?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am creating a YAML Pipeline where I am planning to use the values stored in the variables or variable group or the values from key vault on running the pipeline.

Inside pipeline---->Library-----> I have created a variable group and stored a variable.

Now, In my YAML Pipeline, I went to action button/ three dots----> triggers----->Variable Group-----> Link my Variable Group

Then, In my YAML pipeline, I am trying to call the variable using the following two options:

**option 1:** $(factoryName)

**option 2:** $[variables.factoryName]

But the variable is not getting called and I am getting the following error:

**##[error]One of the deployment parameters has an empty key.**

Comment: Have you stated your variable group inside your YAML ? `- group: my-variable-group` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

> While creating a YAML Pipeline, can we use library variables?

Please check your key or value of variables in the variable group does not have space in between.

If your value required space then, use `""`.

If above not help you, please share the variable group and the YAML file to us, so that we could test it.